# MassTransit MessageData Management

Tags: masstransit

I have been starting to make greater use of the message data feature of masstransit and am getting to the point needing to manage the message data in the store - i.e. remove old data.

The obvious choice is to have some outside process tidy up data, but clearly a scheduled (or not) clean up could remove data still in use or referenced by error or dead letter queues.

Ideally I would like to limit stored message data retention to messages only in error or dead letter queues, and automatically remove data for messages that have been successfully processed.

What would be the best approach to achieve this with MassTransit? Perhaps with a MiddleWare approach or similar, and if that is the case what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

Manual cleanup is recommended, using whatever makes sense for the repository in use. Because messages may still be in queues, or in error/dead-letter queues as you pointed out, it is really up to development/operations team to know when the right time is to remove older message data.

I'd suggest monitoring and managing the error/dead-letter queues more aggressively, keeping them empty. And then, just figure a good timeframe to delete old message data - one week, ten days, whatever - and deal with it that way.

> I have had a backlog item to come up with a way to automatically manage message data, but since message data can be forwarded (using the same stored data) either via publish or send, there is no good way to track references.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I had come to the same conclusion. A little after I posted the question I realized that, in fact, I have situations where the message data is forwarded without being recreated.